# Number Format Exception in Solr

Tags: solr

I am trying to do data import handler in Solr.But not able to index the data from solr using the full_import command.It is giving a NumberFormatException even though I have defined the fields as string in `schema.xml`.I am using `5.2.1` version of Solr.

```
    WARN  - 2015-07-09 07:14:19.137; 
[   king] org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter; 
Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [id=1, name=Ajay, _version_=1506201891385638912])
    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=1] Error adding field 'name'='Ajay' msg=For input string: "Ajay"
        at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:176)
```

Can you please clarify what am I doing wrong here.When I do the same procedure in techproducts example it works fine.

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">157</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">full-import</str>
<str name="mode">debug</str>
<arr name="documents">
<lst>
<arr name="id">
<int>1</int>
</arr>
<arr name="name">
<str>Ajay</str>
</arr>
<arr name="_version_">
<long>1506202992068526080</long>
</arr>
</lst>
<lst>
<arr name="id">
<int>2</int>
</arr>
<arr name="name">
<str>Karan</str>
</arr>
<arr name="_version_">
<long>1506202992072720384</long>
</arr>
</lst>
<lst>
<arr name="id">
<int>3</int>
</arr>
<arr name="name">
<str>Raj</str>
</arr>
<arr name="_version_">
<long>1506202992077963264</long>
</arr>
</lst>
<lst>
<arr name="id">
<int>4</int>
</arr>
<arr name="name">
<str>Ramesh</str>
</arr>
<arr name="_version_">
<long>1506202992083206144</long>
</arr>
</lst>
</arr>
<lst name="verbose-output"/>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">4</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2015-07-09 07:31:48</str>
<str name="Total Documents Failed">4</str>
<str name="Time taken">0:0:0.133</str>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: Can you post your schema file? Also can you paste the entire exception? The exception you have given doesn't say anywhere that it's number format exception.

Comment: Solved this by adding _s to the field in the data-config.xml.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding _s to the string field in the data-config.xml.Solved the issue.